# Rails - Updating Boolean Attribute in a model on Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an app that lets users purchase items from an online store. I followed the RailsCasts episodes, and built my `OrdersController` like so.

```
  def create
    @order = current_cart.build_order(order_params)
    @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        Item.where(email: Order.last.email).last.purchased == true  
        PurchaseMailer.confirmation_email(Item.last.email).deliver                        
        flash[:notice] = "Thanks for your purchase"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:danger] = "Something was wrong"
        redirect_to :back
       end
     else
       render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

I recently decided to add an attribute to my items, which says whether or not they've been purchased or not. Items in the cart have not yet been purchased. I created a migration, giving all items a purchased attribute, that is a `boolean`.

By default, items are not purchased, so the default value is false.

```
class AddPurchasedToItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :items, :purchased, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

That's why I added this line of code to my `Orders#Create` action.

```
Item.where(email: Order.last.email).last.purchased == true
```

Here I was setting the value of purchased from false to true. However, when I load up rails console

```
Item.last.purchased
=> false
```

It looks like the value still isn't being stored

Comment: does your Item have a default scope that sets an order by.  If not you can't rely on last to return to return the same item all the time, or the last item, since it is DB dependent which order things are returned in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another response points out, you're using the `==` to assign a value, which isn't right. You need `=` instead.

And you have to save an item after you assign a value to it.

An example:

```
conditions = {email: Order.last.email} # using your conditions
item = Item.find_by(conditions)
item.purchased = true
item.save # this is what you're missing
Item.find(item.id).purchased # will be true
```

Another way to update is the following:

```
item.update_attribute(:purchased, true)
```

Yet another way is to call `update_all` on the ActiveRecord::Relation object like so:

```
# update all items that match conditions:
Item.where(conditions).update_all(purchased: true)
```

Which method you choose may depend on the scenario as `update_all` doesn't run the callbacks you specify in the model.

In your case however, all you're missing is the `item.save` line.

Comment: Yeah if you're updating the attribute through the `=` method. After you assign an instance of Item a new attribute value like that, you need to call `save` on the same instance for it to persist in the databse.

Answer (score 0):

`Item.where(email: Order.last.email).last.purchased == true`

You're using a `==` operator to try to assign a value. Try using `=` instead.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one. Thanks for pointing that out